# Getting assert at fx_muxer.cpp:316 upon startup of .NET Core App 1.0 on Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net, .net, ubuntu, .net-standard

I'm seeing the following output from my .NET Core App 1.0 on Ubuntu after adding a dependency for my PCL that targets `netstandard1.3`:

```
foo: /opt/code/src/corehost/cli/fxr/fx_muxer.cpp:316: static pal::string_t fx_muxer_t::resolve_fx_dir(host_mode_t, const pal::string_t &, const runtime_config_t &, const pal::string_t &): Assertion `mode != host_mode_t::standalone' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

That line of code is:

```
// No FX resolution for standalone apps.
assert(mode != host_mode_t::standalone);
```

This didn't happen to me before, so I'm unsure where to start looking. How is this `host_mode_t` resolved on startup?

It seems to me the problem is that **some dependency resolution is happening that doesn't need to, because of a mistake in a configuration file?**

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is the full output of the app upon startup once I set `COREHOST_TRACE=1`:

```
Tracing enabled
--- Invoked dotnet [version: 1.1.0, commit hash: 0bc55b1fcc0bd58987bf96683c15596918db2b13] main = { ./foo --staging }
Resolved fxr [/var/www/html/foo/staging/libhostfxr.so]...
Tracing enabled
--- Invoked hostfxr [commit hash: 928f77c4bc3f49d892459992fb6e1d5542cb5e86] main Own DLL
ath=[/var/www/html/foo/staging/foo.dll]
Checking if CoreCLR path exists=[/var/www/html/foo/staging/libcoreclr.so]
Detecting mode...
CoreCLR present in own dir [/var/www/html/foo/staging] and checking if [foo.deps.json] file present=[1]
--- Executing in standalone mode...
Treating application '/var/www/html/foo/staging/foo.dll' as a managed executable.
App runtimeconfig.json from [/var/www/html/foo/staging/foo.dll]
Runtime config is cfg=/var/www/html/foo/staging/foo.runtimeconfig.json
dev=/var/www/html/foo/staging/foo.runtimeconfig.dev.json
Attempting to ead runtime config: /var/www/html/foo/staging/foo.runtimeconfig.json
Attempting to read dev runtime config: /var/www/html/foo/staging/foo.runtimeconfig.dev.json
Runtime config[/var/www/html/foo/staging/foo.runtimeconfig.json] is valid=[1]
foo: /opt/code/src/corehost/cli/fxr/fx_muxer.cpp:316: static pal::string_t fx_muxer_t::resolve_fx_dir(host_mode_t, const pal::string_t &, const runtime_config_t &, const pal::string_t &): Assertion `mode != host_mode_t::standalone' failed. Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue was twofold:

1. I was using rsync to publish the app to my server, but I wasn't deleting files no longer in use, so the dependency configuration files were still present;
2. I had, at some point, added "platform" as the "type" for "Microsoft.NETCore.App" in my dependencies for the "netcoreapp1.0" target. This was causing a DLL to be generated instead of a standalone executable.